# How can I let users download an image file onto their computer

Tags: python, file, python-requests, python-imaging-library

So I have this project that I want to build for users to remove a background from an image. The process is supposed to be simple: User uploads an image -> The image got processed(with background removed) -> User download the processed image.

Now the problem I am facing is the downloading part. When the image the user uploaded is finished processing, the processed version is saved onto the program directory but I want it to be downloadable to the user's computer/device instead.

The processed image is gotten as a response. I am able to write the response.content to a file but my goal is to allow a user to download it on their device. I have tried using the Pillow(PIL) library but i could't find a way still.

Please help out.

```
response = requests.post(
    'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg',
    files={'image_file': open(filepath, 'rb')},
    data={'size': 'auto'},
    headers={'X-Api-Key': 'tMxQo9fLnFG6hrMoiKaezVwH'},
  )
  if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
      // this saves the image as file(no-bg.png) onto my working directory
      with open('no-bg.png', 'wb') as out:
          out.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to solve the problem. I used cloudinary api to upload the processed image and there allow the users to download the image through the api response